# Position absolute table inside div in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, html-table, position, absolute

I have a **table with position absolute inside a div** and want that table to stay with the text inside the div. Firefox does this correct, Chrome needed display:-webkit-box; to make it work.

But my question is, **how to fix this for Internet Explorer?** (IE 9 and up)

```css
.container { 
  width:250px; 
  height:250px; 
  background:red; 
  position:relative; 
}
.container table { 
  position:absolute; 
  top:20px; left:100px; 
  display:-moz-box; 
  display:-webkit-box; 
  display:-ms-flex; 
  display:box; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wLLGp/

Note: this is a simplified version of the code, I can't really change the table in a div which I know solves the problem.

Edit: I am using responsive design so only the outer div (.container) can have a width.

Answer (score 0):

remove all those `display` properties, and give your `<table>` the the `width` it needs:

container width : 250px - left 100px : 150px;

```
.container table {
    left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wLLGp/5/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using responsive design and only the outer div (.container) can have a width. So this does not work for me. But thanks for the reply.